# Trouble while adding column - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, updates

just a simple problem (I hope !)

I've got a ***void*** method which add a column to a table.

Why if I call that method programmatically (ex: [self method] ) my table ***won't update*** and instead if i call it through an *IBAction* (pushing a button from app) it *works* ?
Actually i can see from the log that the **method is called in both cases** but update data just with IBAction.

**the method:**

```
- (IBAction)void {
    NSTableColumn *column = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"1"];
    [column setWidth:50];
    [tableData addTableColumn:column];
    [tableData reloadData];

    [[column headerCell] setStringValue:@"aColumn"];
    NSLog(@"Method called"); //The method is called in both cases
}
```

I can't find out what I am doing wrong.

(New to cocoa programming)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you call this programmatically?  You might have called it before the view was loaded in an init method instead of something else like awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got different results. It was called fine from code (and the table updated), but not from the button (and the log wasn't run either when attempting to call from the button).

The problem is the method name -- you shouldn't name a method void. Do you not get the error message in the console: "Could not connect the action void: to target of class AppDelegate"
The compiler won't even allow me to connect that method to the button (it looks like I can in IB, but I get that error message, and if I put the method in the .h file, it has no circle next to it that shows whether it's connected or not).